# Struggling to Understand Byte Array to Double Conversion in Java

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, double, byte

I've made some functions in javascript to handle converting values to byte arrays, to be sent to a Java webserver where they will be read.

When writing an int, in js, I used:

```
function writeInt(num) {
   let arr = new Uint32Array([
   (num & 0xff000000) >> 24,
   (num & 0x00ff0000) >> 16,
   (num & 0x0000ff00) >> 8,
   (num & 0x000000ff)
   ]);
   buf.push(Buffer.from(arr));
}
```

The integer is received in little endian, and while I don't understand bitwise operation completely, I got some help from stack and google. I read the integer in Java with the following (bs being my stream variable):

`(bs.readByte() << 24) + (bs.readByte() << 16) + (bs.readByte() << 8) + (bs.readByte());`

But when I tried to write a double, I used the writeDoubleLE(number) function as follows:

```
const double = Buffer.allocUnsafe(8);
double.writeDoubleLE(num);
buffer.push(Buffer.from(double));
```

and I used this function in Java:

```
return Double.longBitsToDouble(
((byte) (bs.readByte() & 0xFFL)) << 56 |
((byte) (bs.readByte() & 0xFFL)) << 48 |
((byte) (bs.readByte() & 0xFFL)) << 40 |
((byte) (bs.readByte() & 0xFFL)) << 32 |
((byte) (bs.readByte() & 0xFFL)) << 24 |
((byte) (bs.readByte() & 0xFFL)) << 16 |
((byte) (bs.readByte() & 0xFFL)) << 8 |
((byte) (bs.readByte() & 0xFFL)));
```

I tried with some random numbers like 22.5, and now, the values are obviously wrong, giving me stuff like 2.0789966E-317 and 5.32223134E-315.

I have been messing with the code in Java because the sent bytes appear correct, but it just doesn't work.

Finally, I tried writeDoubleBE, and the Java code can read it successfully. This feels wrong because the bytes for the double are obviously now not consistent with the format of the other bytes in the array. I'd rather understand what's going on and why this isn't working. It seems like my javascript code is writing it wrong, but I am not sure if it's the JS or Java.

I hope someone with more knowledge about this can explain it to me and point out what I am doing wrong when writing/reading the values.

Comment: Consider using a `ByteBuffer` configured with the right byte-order and use its [`getDouble()`\(https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#getDouble()) method.

Comment: Thank you, I had considered ByteBuffer but I really wanted to get these functions working with the bitwise operations for better understanding.

Comment: I guess I didn't have my coffee yet when I read your initial question, but your `writeInt` is actually writing big-endian, not little-endian, so using `writeDoubleBE` and keeping your Java code as-is would solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, though I still am not sure why it works this way (with the first byte being << 0 instead of << 56)

```
long byte1 = bs.readByte();
long byte2 = bs.readByte();
long byte3 = bs.readByte();
long byte4 = bs.readByte();
long byte5 = bs.readByte();
long byte6 = bs.readByte();
long byte7 = bs.readByte();
long byte8 = bs.readByte();
return Double.longBitsToDouble(byte1 + (byte2 << 8) + (byte3 << 16) + (byte4 << 24) + (byte5 << 32) + (byte6 << 40) + (byte7 << 48) + (byte8 << 56));
```